# Maintaining data global state for multiple button clicks

Tags: android-layout, android-intent, global-variables, bundles

I have an Inspection Form for an Android tablet that has 5 activity pages and approximately 30 button clicks.  Each button click generates a TextView value which are then compiled at the end of the application to create a report.

My issue is this:  is there any other way to maintain state between activities and to carry the data from all the activities to the report stage WITHOUT using Intent and Bundles.

I have read everything thing I can about Intent and Bundles and it seems to be an awkward way of doing things.  Being a C++ programmer I am use to addresses and pointers to reach out and get any data value I want, even in some cases using global pointers to maintain state.

Having 30 buttons to create 30 Bundle variables (to which then need to be retrieve by a switch statement) seems overkill when you already have a button ID and a value saved to in a memory address in the application.

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Bob

Comment: okay.. as a new member it is too early to answer own question.  I found this: Maintaining global Application state using the APPLICATION CLASS.  Found a good article here:  http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend the Application class. You can just declare your own class with static (class) variables. Like this:

```
public class Globals {
    public static String text1;
    public static String text2;
    ...
}
```

You can access these variables from anywhere in your code, like this:

```
Globals.text1 = "stuff";
```

or

```
String text1 = Globals.text1;
```